# Function as argument to `.appendTo()`

Tags: jquery

I would like use `.appendTo()` on different elements determined by a function. For example, I want to be able to do:

```
$myElement.appendTo(function () {
     if(Math.random() < 0.5) return $el1; else return $el2;
});
```

However, the jQuery documentation doesn't cover the case of a function given as an argument to `.appendTo()`.

Is there a specific reason why the jQuery team would not allow for such a feature, and is there a smart way around it (maybe by redefining the `.appendTo()` function)? Many other jQuery functions allow functions as argument...

Comment: `$myElement.appendTo( Math.random() < 0.5 ? $el1 : $el2 );`

Comment: Have you tried using a self-executing function? .appendto((function() { ... })());

Comment: @Nick: "Self-executing function"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to  make your code work :

- passing a self-calling function as parameter (which would actually mean that you're passing the function's return value)
- pass a conditional statement that returns the desired object
- filter the elements before the `appendTo` call
- etc

but if you truly want to make the jquery `appendTo` method to take a function as a parameter, you should extend the `appendTo` method yourself :

```
(function($){
    var originalAppendTo = $.fn.appendTo;
    $.fn.appendTo = function(f){
        el = typeof f === 'function'
            ?  f.call(this)
            :  f;
        return originalAppendTo.call(this,el);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

then you can pass a function as parameter to `appendTo` :

```
$myElement.appendTo(function () {
    if(Math.random() < 0.5) return $el1; else return $el2;
});
```

Here's a working example :

### http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/ZEnMQ/

Answer (score 1):

Generally, don't you filter/select the elements **before** you do stuff to them?

Answer (score 1):

You should feed `.appendTo` with a result of function (or [its immediate invocation](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)), not a function itself, for example:

```
$myElement.appendTo(
    (function() {
        if(Math.random() < 0.5) return $el1; else return $el2;
    })()
);
```

Comment: I would recommend against patterns that stack parens (like `)))`).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Whitespace added :)

Answer (score 1):

The `filter` method takes a function. Do something like this:

```
$("#someselector").filter(function () {
    return index == 1 || $(this).attr("id") == "fourth"; // or whatever
}).append($myElelment);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn this code on it head with $.append with something like:

```
function append($myElement) {
    if(Math.random() < 0.5) return $el1.append($myElement); else return $el2.append($myElemen);
}
```

I'm not sure why jquery wouldn't allow the functionality you would want.